# JQGrid-Trirand. How to Edit Fields?

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I have one page where i have bind data by using JqGrid, but My requirement is In editing one row of a grid, the editable fields must **NOT BE** builtin fields( builtin textboxs) i want to bind that to other textboxes, check boxes which are outside grid. The data which i want to edit must be supplied to other input controls other than jqgrid builtin input controls, Finally IS THIS POSSIBLE???

Hope iam clear with my question.

Please do help me in reply saying either YES or NO or How, and why.

edited

[image]

Comment: Any thing is possible man if approach is right, but first tell me what you have tried till now.

Comment: I have done Noraml Edit process and my data is updating too in this process, but i want that controls NOT to be in BuiltIn Grid but from outside of grid. so how to pass row data to other controls?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understand correctly what you mean, but it seems that you should just use [form editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing) mode. To activate it on the client side you should just add `editable: true` property to all columns which are editable or use the option `cmTemplate: {editable: true}` which makes default value of `editable` for all columns as `true`. After it you can for example use [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anavigator#definition) to add Add, Edit and Delete buttons in the pager. The functionality on the client side will be ready after that. Now you have to implement editing part in the server code only. If you use commercial version of jqGrid like jqSuite you should address to the documentation or [demos](http://www.trirand.net/demo.aspx) for more details.

Comment: But what exactly i need is NOT this, this is already implemented and we are using it too.., I DONT WANT to use form editing mode, i want Rows column data in EXTERNAL TextBoxes NOT in BuildIn TextBoxes( Form editing mode) can we do like that??

Comment: @Pink: Could you define more clear what you mean under "EXTERNAL TextBoxes" or post a link or a picture which clear that?

Comment: My image is not getting posted Here i dont have many reputations to get image posted here., so now???

Comment: @Pink: You can post URL to the image for example. I will modify your question and will include the image itself inside.

Comment: @Pink: You don't posted any code which you use. There are *many* different implementation ways which one can use. If I will just guess what you did I will just spend my time and probably provide solutions which con't help you really. For example you can use `getCol`, `getRowData` or `getLocalRow` [methods](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) to get the data from any row. If you need to have solution which is specific for commertial version of jqGrid you should post the question to [trirand jqSuite forum](http://www.trirand.net/forum/).

Answer (score 0):

try this
http://www.trirand.net/examples/grid/selection/selectedrow_client/default.aspx

or
Try this

```
<ClientSideEvents BeforeEditDialogShown="beforeEdit"/>


   <script type="text/javascript">

   function beforeEdit(rowID) {
      var grid = jQuery("#<%= JQGrid1.ClientID %>");
      lastSelectedRow = grid.getGridParam("selrow");
   };



   </script>
```